# Узнать какой элемент выполнил обращение к функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Есть некая функция отправляющая значения со шкалы, есть 3 шкалы вызывающие эту функцию в момент активации и передающие ей значения. Вопрос в следующем каким: образом определить с какой именно шкалы передаются значения.

Пример кода:

```
Degree1 = Scale(master, **options, command=send)
Degree2 = Scale(master, **options, command=send)
Degree3 = Scale(master, **options, command=send)

def send(value):
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через лямбду передавать элемент управления в обработчик:

```
def send(widget, value):
    print(widget, value)

Degree1 = Scale(master, **options)
Degree1.config(command=lambda value: send(Degree1, value))

Degree2 = Scale(master, **options)
Degree2.config(command=lambda value: send(Degree2, value))

Degree3 = Scale(master, **options)
Degree3.config(command=lambda value: send(Degree3, value))
```

Если нужен номер, а не сам виджет:

```
def send(widget_number, value):
    print(widget_number, value)

Degree1 = Scale(master, **options, command=lambda value: send(1, value))
Degree2 = Scale(master, **options, command=lambda value: send(2, value))
Degree3 = Scale(master, **options, command=lambda value: send(3, value))
```

Если вдруг нужно будет создавать виджеты в цикле, то номер в лямбду нужно будет передавать немного по-другому:

```
scales = []

for i in range(3):
    scale = Scale(master, **options, command=lambda value, i=i: send(i, value))
    scale.pack()
    scales.append(scale)
```

Если просто написать `command=lambda value: send(i, value)`, то лямбда "завяжется" на локальную переменную `i`, и при изменении значения любой из шкал будет показывать последнее (текущее) значение переменной `i` (в данном случае 2).

Comment: А можно ли узнать конкретный номер шкалы вызывающей функцию?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.